# Как разделить трафик на linux?

Tags: linux

Есть два провайдера на устройстве, один дешевый и медленный а другой дорогой но быстрый. Как пример: Хочу чтобы через дешевый работала только почта а ютубчик и другой трафик шел через дорогой.

Как настроить маршрутизацию и фаирвол (iptables)?

Comment: вам наверное нужен балансировщик

Comment: Как-то так сделать
http://davidstangeby.blogspot.com/2012/10/port-based-routing-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: http://lartc.org

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1185861/linux-routing-based-on-domain-names

Answer (score 3):

Вы знакомы с моделью OSI?
1.
Тут такое дело "ютубчик" это уровень приложений или хз, может теперь из-за шифрования считается представлений(7,6), а маршрутизация это уровень сетевой.

Если отвечать вам как юзеру - то ищите приложение, которое такое делает. это более или менее обеспечивает ваше решение. Особенно если приложение - некий онлайн сервис, а не одностороняя программа.

2.
Простое(бесплатное, но реально связанное с маршрутизацией) решение на Linux это найти в Ripe.net желаемые блоки адресов и прописать с рута в консоли каждый большой маршрут 2 раза на разные ip gateway(или интерфейсы в сторону операторов) но с разными метриками:

1. Вот например 2 маршрута, разогнанные в разные каналы -

   route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw eth01 metric 100

   route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw eth02 metric 200

   route add -net 11.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw eth02 metric 100

   route add -net 11.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw eth01 metric 200

Это запись двух маршрутов значит, что при падении(физическом, не логическом, для логического нужен динамический протокол маршрутизации с оператором) - начнёт использоваться маршрут с метрикой 200, а при обычном деле - будет ходить через 100.

Не пишите одинаковых метрик. стандартное ядро Linux не будет балансировать трафик, но может получиться какое-то трудно диагностируемое адище.

---

такие команды можно раскидать в bash скрипт и стартовать его в автозагрузке.
но полнокровно эта схема будет работать .. так по-чесноку при полностью рабочих обоих каналах, так как Linux не будет ничего знать о доступности связи по каналам.

так что без легковесной bgp4(серые номера автономных систем) сессии с обоими операторами и full view .. ну или операторы могут другие наборы кидать - увы только через приложения. Но и там есть засады, ввиду того, что они только пытаются предполагать состояние каналов и подменить функционал bgp частично.

для легковесного bgp см. Zebra наугад - [вот](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/LARTC/x3036.html) - простое объяснение настройки (там cisco like command interface)

Comment: программа route уже двадцать лет как забродила и покрылась плесенью. [лучше не использовать ни её, ни ifconfig — они работают некорректно](https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712).

Comment: да. 
пожалуй стоит отметить, что это общая теория, а не руководство к действию. так как действительно там товарищи правильно пишут - за последние лет 5 народилось в среде разработчиков новое поколение, которые вместо того чтобы что-то изучать, и дописывать открытый код, -  написали своё и подменили этим то, что было. :) 
 В итоге - действительно реальные команды, названия интерфейсов и способы их прописи лучше посмотреть отдельно, а мою мысль использовать только как общий принцип.

Comment: вообще-то Алексей Кузнецов переписал сетевую подсистему программы linux 20 лет назад. [вот тут](https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?p=1170457&#p1170457) я вкратце изложил то, что удалось насобирать по интернетам в отношении того — **зачем** это было сделано. // просто «кардинально поменять поведение программы» — слишком многое поломается. а так iproute внедрялся медленно и постепенно, без резкого «блин, все скрипты конфигурации сети полетели к чертям!»

Comment: Ну в порядке продолжения бессмысленного флуда 20 лет назад ни о чём подобном особо не слышали. Мы почти все тогда юзали freebsd 4 и компилировались ядра у нас бывало по нескольку часов. А над окнами ржали так, что kde под freebsd до сих пор помнят как шутку. 
 Тогда в Linux уходили от совсем другого набора команд управления интерфейсами как раз в ipconfig/route. ТО что вы описываете в обиходе начало появляться лет 5-7 назад.

Comment: «25 января 1999: Linux версии 2.2.0» — в этой версии уже была новая сетевая подсистема. но для очень многих пользователй iproute2 «не появилась» до сих пор: так и продолжают (даже в публичных постах) писать ifconfig/route/arp.

Comment: Всё может быть, но я ж не историк. Я тогда реальные сервера развёртывал, а тогда, знаете ли.. у вас слишком радужные представления о том, что за пакеты поступали в качестве новых решений и какой это был мир. :) usenet и книжка со списком команд это все помощники в сборке ОС из исходников... в usenet за помощью по iproute2 пришёл? там только что обратили внимание что существует что-то подключенное на востоке к райпу со своим дурацким мнением... но я честно .. раньше года 2005 этого слова в линукс пакетах не помню вообще... русский знаете ли был моветоном. не то что пакеты.